# Send data from an array in api and show response in next screen React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I want to send my data from textinputs from an array, the reason why I choose array is because the api which I am calling is basically an array, all I want to do is to set those values from textinput to api and show response to next screen.
Here's my screen One which is taking these values and sending it to api, but problem is it is not sending value neither showing me response onto next screen:

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            ze:[userid="",
            ID="",
            titlex="",
            switchValue=false,]
        }   
    }
 handleSubmit(){  
     fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", {
        method: "POST",
       // headers: headers,
        body:  JSON.stringify({
          userId:this.state.ze.userid,
          id:this.state.ze.ID,
          title:this.state.ze.titlex,
          completed:this.state.ze.switchValue,
        })
     })
     .then(function(response){ 
      return response.json();   

     })
     .then(function(z){ 
     console.log(z)
     });
     this.props.navigation.navigate('Pg',{value:this.state.ze});
    }
```

This is my next screen on which it will show me response this is what I've done so far and I dont know how to show response from an array to next screen:

```
 componentDidMount = () => {
      const item = JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.getParam('value'));
       Alert.alert(item.id);
     }
     render() {
        return (
           <View>
              <Text>
               {/* Name:{this.state.} */}
              </Text>
           </View>
        )
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
this.state={
            ze:[userid="",
            ID="",
            titlex="",
            switchValue=false,]
        }
```

Which is in the form of Array, So you have to access it like

```
item[index].id
```

or use the

```
array.map((item, index){
return (
  item.ID
)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending it correctly but you're not reading it correctly.

Instead of this:

```
const item = JSON.stringify(this.props.navigation.getParam('value'));
```

Simply do this:

```
const item = this.props.navigation.getParam('value');
```

now to quickly display it, you can use something like this in your JSX:

```
<Text>{JSON.stringify(item)}</Text>
```

For something more user-friendly, each item on its own line, you can try something like this in your JSX:

```
{!!item.length && item.map(i => <Text>i</Text>)}
```

Of course, it depends on what type of items your array contains. Just adjust the code above.

Comment: Not showing me any values in next screen, I think the problem also lies in my screen 1, because when I did log no value has been sent to api from screen 1

Comment: @TalhaNadeem You're sending the body as a string. It should be an object. No need to use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: I have tried exactly what u did but it is not showing me response on next screen one more thing, I called an api with only on field and the same code worked for me but for array it is not.

Comment: @TalhaNadeem Your API call is always unsuccessful, correct?

Comment: @TalhaNadeem Alright, but that's not the primary issue here. The issue is that when you pass the array to the next screen, it doesn't detect its content. Did you try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.ze))` right before the navigation? Make sure the state actually has some data.